# Editing HDF5 matrix values

Tags: python, hdf5, h5py

I am trying to edit a dataset that has been given to me in an hdf5 format, and resave it. I have been able to edit values in hdf5 files before, but it seems that in this particular case my old method does not work (I will show both examples below).

I have a 3D dataset of shape (101, 4, 2) that I extract from an HDF5 file. For the purposes of this example, I then try to set each of the values to the float value 1.0.

```
file_name = r'C:\Labber\Data\2018\06\Data_0601\CSing.hdf5'
f = h5py.File(file_name, 'r+')
h5entry = f['/Data/Data']

for i in range(len(h5entry[:,0,0])):
    print(h5entry[i][0][1]) #prints 0.0
    h5entry[i][0][1] = 1.0 
    print(h5entry[i][0][1]) #still prints 0.0
```

If I create a numpy array instead of a reference to the HDF5 dataset, I can get this to work.

```
file_name = r'C:\Labber\Data\2018\06\Data_0601\CSing.hdf5'
f = h5py.File(file_name, 'r+')
entry = np.array(f['/Data/Data'])

for i in range(len(entry[:,0,0])):
    print(entry[i][0][1]) #prints 0.0
    entry[i][0][1] = 1.0 
    print(entry[i][0][1]) #prints 1.0
```

But then I have the problem of entry being in a numpy array format, and I cannot easily set the dataset equal to the array. I potentially could create a new dataset from this array, delete the old one, and reassign the new one, but that seems like a pretty clunky way of doing things.

Additionally, I have been able to directly edit HDF5 keys previously, which makes this all the more confusing to me. For example, I have done the following successfully before

```
file_name = r'C:\Labber\Data\2018\06\Data_0601\CSing.hdf5'
f = h5py.File(file_name, 'r+')
entry = f['Step list'][i]
entry['use_relations'] = relations
f['Step list'][i] = entry
```

And this works. Any ideas on what's going on here and how I can accomplish this in the most efficient way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with multi step indexing

```
h5entry[i][0][1] = 1.0
```

try

```
h5entry[i,0,1] = 1.0
```

`h5entry[i][0][1]` is ok for fetching values, but doesn't work for setting because `h5entry[i]` is a copy of the dataset, not a `view`. `h5entry[i]` is an array, not a dataset.

---

```
entry[i][0][1] = 1.0
```

works because `entry` is already an `ndarray`, and `entry[i]` is a `view`, as is `entry[i][0]`.  On the other hand, advanced indexing on the array will not work: `entry[[1,2]][:,0][:,1]=3` because `entry[[1,2]]` is a copy.

Because of these nuances with view vs copy, it's usually safer to use the single step indexing, whether working with `h5py` or `ndarray`:

```
entry[[0,1],0,1] = 3
```

Sometimes it helps if we include the implicit `:` when indexing:

```
entry[i,:,:][0,:][1]
```

The code doesn't need it, but I do.  I need a reminder of how many dimensions I'm working with at each stage.

---

```
f['Step list'][i] = entry
```

works because `f['Step list']` is the dataset, not a copy of the dataset.

Comment: thanks for the simple solution and great explanation